# not getting the content part in post only thumbnail and title is display

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row" id="content">
  <?php
   $args = array( 'posts_per_page' =>3, 'category' =>3 );
   $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
   foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : 
  ?>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <h2 style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size: 19px;font-weight:bold;"><?php the_title();?></h2>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <?php echo the_content(); ?>
             <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>
         </div>
         <div class="bar3"></div>
     </div>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">    
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>     
      </div>
</div>
```

This is my code .i did not get the content from the the post the thumbnail and the title are display ..please anybody help me to solve the problem.sorry for my poor english.

Comment: have you added the content in post code is ok  only add wp_reset_query()  after  endforeach;

Comment: thanks i did not get it  sir .i wrote this code in template page .is there any different loop is have

Comment: why are you using the_excerpt() and the_content() both at the same time? You either use the_excerpt() to display only a little detail or the_content() to display everything of the post

Comment: thanks Mr.wingskush i tried but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this...

```
<div class="row" id="content">
    <?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' =>3, 'category' =>3 );
    $rand_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $rand_posts->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $rand_posts->have_posts() ) : $rand_posts->the_post();
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <h2 style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size: 19px;font-weight:bold;"><?php the_title();?></h2>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <?php the_content(); ?>
             <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
         </div>
         <div class="bar3"></div>
     </div>
    <?php 
       endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">    
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>     
      </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will work...

Comment: Have you assign that `template-theme.php` to your visual page From `wp-admin`????

Comment: Thanks friend now  i am getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <div class="row" id="content">
        <?php
       $args = array( 'posts_per_page' =>3, 'category' =>3 );
       $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
       foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
      ?>
          <div class="col-md-8">
             <h2 style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size: 19px;font-weight:bold;"><?php the_title();?></h2>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="thumbnails">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?></a>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                 <?php  the_content(); ?>
                 <?php  the_excerpt(); ?>
             </div>
             <div class="bar3"></div>
         </div>

       <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
          <div class="col-md-4">    
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>     
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing setup_postdata( $post );

Also when you use the_content(); you don't need to add "echo", same with the other queries start with **"the_"**

Please check the get_posts query here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Cheers!